# LWJGL Jumping Down

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm currently building a little game using LWJGL, and I got a Game class which contains my game loop, instances etc... And a Player class which contains a constructor (for x and y coords), logic method for calculations, key presses etc... and a render method for drawing the player on the screen.
For some reason, when I press UP (Key.UP) the player jumps down the floor, and the goes up to the floor (inverted, instead of jumping up and then falling down to the floor).
I would really appreciate if you could tell me what the problem is.

**Game.java:**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;


public class Game {

    static Texture bgTexture;

    static Player player;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, IOException {
        // Initialize
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
        Display.create();

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        bgTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/background.png"));

        player = new Player(50, 200 - 64);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            drawBackground();
            player.render();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void drawBackground() {
        bgTexture.bind();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(bgTexture.getTextureWidth(), 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(bgTexture.getTextureWidth(), bgTexture.getTextureHeight());
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, bgTexture.getTextureHeight());
        glEnd();
    }

}
```

**Player.java**

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;


public class Player {

    public double x, y, xspeed, yspeed;

    private Texture pTexture;

    public Player(double x, double y) throws IOException {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        pTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/player.png"));
    }

    public void logic() {
        x += xspeed;
        y += yspeed;

        yspeed -= 0.4;

        // Collision detection
        if (y <= 480 - 64) {
            y = 480 - 64;
            yspeed = 0;

            if (!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT) && xspeed > 0) xspeed = xspeed * 0.7;
            if (!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT) && xspeed < 0) xspeed = xspeed * 0.7;
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) yspeed = 8;
        }

        // Moving
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) xspeed = 4;
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) xspeed = -4;
    }

    public void render() {
        logic();

        glPushMatrix();
        pTexture.bind();
        glTranslated(x, y, 0);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
        glVertex2d(0, 0);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
        glVertex2d(pTexture.getTextureWidth(), 0);
        glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
        glVertex2d(pTexture.getTextureWidth(), pTexture.getTextureHeight());
        glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
        glVertex2d(0, pTexture.getTextureHeight());
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
    }

}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you. Please make use of your debugger to isolate the problem to a small section of code and context demonstrating the problem and edit your question to include this code as well as other information and state you learned while debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate (0,0) is the top-left of the screen.

```
if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) yspeed = 8;
```

This means that your player accelerates downwards on `KEY_UP`, and

```
yspeed -= 0.4;
```

means "gravity" pulls the player to the top of the screen.

Comment: Yes, I  knew that already, but haven't figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where the (0,0) coordinate is located on your screen?

because if (0,0) is located in the top left corner, 
jumping up would result in a decreased Y-value.

That would explain the jumping down with increasing the Y-value.